# Android alternative to iOS Google Maps API GMSGeometryOffset

Tags: android, ios, google-maps

I am working on an Android version of an Ios app I have developed and are running into problems with differences in the Google Maps API on the two platforms. In Ios I can use the method: [GMSGeometryOffset](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/group___geometry_utils#ga8d6fb874513718f8325ebca9615b051e). However, it is not present in the Android API. Therefore, I am looking for an alternative to this method so that I can calculate a new location based on the current location, a direction/bearing and a distance/radius.

I am using it to Draw a round circle while avoiding the egg shape. My code so far looks like the following. However, it gives me an egg shape unless the current location is directly on top of equator.

```
for(double angle = 0; angle < 2*Math.PI; angle = angle+ Math.PI/resolutionCircle)
        {
            latitude = position.latitude + (radiusCircle * Math.sin(angle));
            longitude = position.longitude + (radiusCircle * Math.cos(angle));

            inner.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude));
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [computeOffset](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#computeOffset(LatLng,%20double,%20double)) method in the Google Maps Android API Utility Library.

It is a static method:

```
public static LatLng computeOffset(LatLng from,
                   double distance,
                   double heading)
```

It returns the LatLng resulting from moving a distance from an origin in the specified heading (expressed in degrees clockwise from north).

You can refer [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/) for more detail about Google Maps Android API Utility Library.

Google Maps' [GitHub page](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.java) also provide its detail implementation:

```
 public static LatLng computeOffset(LatLng from, double distance, double heading) {
        distance /= EARTH_RADIUS;
        heading = toRadians(heading);
        // http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#LL
        double fromLat = toRadians(from.latitude);
        double fromLng = toRadians(from.longitude);
        double cosDistance = cos(distance);
        double sinDistance = sin(distance);
        double sinFromLat = sin(fromLat);
        double cosFromLat = cos(fromLat);
        double sinLat = cosDistance * sinFromLat + sinDistance * cosFromLat * cos(heading);
        double dLng = atan2(
                sinDistance * cosFromLat * sin(heading),
                cosDistance - sinFromLat * sinLat);
        return new LatLng(toDegrees(asin(sinLat)), toDegrees(fromLng + dLng));
    }
```

Comment: how big should be that distance? in meters or in km..if i want to consider the corners from the center of the map?